# Log file not being updated/created using log4j in java

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to capture the logs using log4j in Java.  The executeable is in linux envirnment and it displays the logging message, however, it is not writing into the log file.  I am using log4j.xml and this is what I have so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="LocalFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File"   value="logs/error.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="1" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout"/>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value ="Debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I am not clear how the java program knows where the xml file is located.  I think that is the problem.  And, this is how I setup in the code,

```
log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Any help would be appreicate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the `log4j.xml` file on the classpath of your application and log4j will find it automatically to configure itself with the very first time you use log4j.

However, by calling `BasicConfigurator.configure()`, you are undoing any configuration done by the XML file - as this sets up a console appender to the root logger only.

Run your java program with `-Dlog4j.debug` to have log4j output a bunch of information about where it is looking for the configuration files when it starts up.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like it is not finding the xml file,  how do I set to the classpath?  just like, Classpath=/mylog/log4j.xml?  Thanks, again.

Comment: Okay, I got it now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** On the Windows env , 
  Even if all the parameters are right , need to make sure that the path to the file is absolute and that is separated by " / " rather than the normal "\" .

While deciding on the path , "\" are ignored and so it becomes one large name .

And hence it might seem that nothing's been written , it actually is that it's getting written at a different place . :)

**2)** And on Eclipse , to try out the option that the previous answer by "matt B" suggests..

Go to RUN > RUN Configurations >  Arguments [tab ] and put in the value in the VM arguments > Apply and RUN .
  Obviously your file should have main..