# Log4J not creating one of many log files

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

**Background:**

We have an application deployed on JBoss v7.1.1. It is configured to log to multiple distinct log files in the **same** directory. All of the them get rolled over everyday. We recently found that one of the ~5 log files never got any log lines for the past 2 weeks or so (and didn't get rolled over).

I did a search here and found no question having this problem; hence asking a new one.

**log4j configuration**:
Configuration of one of many other loggers:

```
#Concise logger
log4j.appender.ConciseLogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ConciseLogger.File=../standalone/log/xyzlog/splunk-metrics.log
log4j.appender.ConciseLogger.Append=true
log4j.appender.ConciseLogger.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.ConciseLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConciseLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} -%X{txnid}- %m%n
log4j.appender.ConciseLogger.Encoding=UTF-8
```

There are other log configurations *in the same configuration file* that log to the **exact same** location. The lines look like below:

```
..
log4j.appender.CacheManifestLogger.File=../standalone/log/xyzlog/cacheManifest.log
..
..
log4j.appender.APPTXNLOGGER.File=../standalone/log/xyzlog/transactions.log
```

**Problem / Details**

- We have ~5 distinct log files that we log to. All get logged to the same identical folder.
- Only `ConciseLogger` (above) stopped working from the past two weeks.
- The exact same build works on other (non-production) machines. In a way, "It works in my machine" ;-)

**Guesses at what might be wrong**

- Disk fills up? Nope, the disk is only 20% full
- File Permissions? Nope, other files are being logged without issues
- Issues with the actual code? Not likely, because things are committed to SVN, and the logging specific code has been untouched for months together. This does not explain why this has to fail just 2 weeks before.
- Any traces of log4j specific exception in the JBoss server log? Nope, didnt find any.
- Log4J Internals: May be it spawns a new thread for each of the category, and the thread dies for this specific category of mine.

  - In this case is there a way to debug this?
- Log4J specific issues? See below..

**Debugging**

- Used the same build, deployed to another machine -- Works - No issues with logging!
- As per [@Matt b's suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466389/227884), I tried to start JBoss with an addtional `-Dlog4j.debug`. **I found the log lines for each of the categories except `ConciseLogging`. This means log4j is ignoring one single category. This is really weird.**

[The lines of the output of `grep log4j server.log` has been pasted here](http://ideone.com/HsxJcW). In the entire output linked, I do not see any entry that relates to `ConciseLogging`.

And here is the original log4j configuration file: http://ideone.com/wiH0VU

**My Questions**

- Has anyone of you experienced something of this sort before? Is this a log4j bug that it simply refuses to parse one of the many categories?

  - Or is this problem with the configuration file linked above? (I doubt it because it has never failed any time before)
- Is there any general debugging step that I can take from here?

**Environment**

- JBoss v7.1.1
- Ubuntu 12.04 (on Amazon EC2)
- Java SDK

Comment: My first hunch is that there may be local settings that are overriding the settings you posted.  Has that app been changed recently?

Answer (score 0):

have you restarted the JBoss since it stopped logging?

i had an issue once that a log was missing and we couldn't find any evidence of why shouldn't it be created, we still believe the cause was a bad start up of the server (could be that the service that the log is monitoring didn't start/work), after a fresh restart the missing log appeared.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: its a question to op for resolution.

Comment: Requesting clarification to the OP must be posted as a comment, not as an answer. (you need 50 reputation points to be able to comment)